# Program adds empty spaces so it won't detect correctly later

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a game with Python and Pygame and I can't get game saving to work at all.

```
f event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: ##########WRITE################
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            print("Writing File")
            with open ("Saves/testListSave.txt","w") as f:
                f.write("1\n")
                f.write("2\n")
                f.write("3\n")
                f.write("4\n")
                f.write("5\n")
                f.write("6\n")
                f.write("7\n")
                f.write("8\n")
                f.write("9\n")
                f.close()
```

This part works just fine. It writes to file just like it should do it writes number beneath of each other.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But then comes the problem; when I try to read the file it adds these empty lines under each line (at least it looks like that in console)

```
if event.key == pygame.K_t:
            with open("Saves/testListSave.txt","r") as f:
                data1 = f.readline()
                data2 = f.readline()
                data3 = f.readline()
                data4 = f.readline()
                data5 = f.readline()
                data6 = f.readline()
                data7 = f.readline()
                data8 = f.readline()
                data9 = f.readline()

                print("print DATA")
                print(data1)
                print(data2)
                print(data3)
                print(data4)
                print(data5)
                print(data6)
                print(data7)
                print(data8)
                print(data9)


                if data5 == 5:
                    print("data5 = 5")
```

This makes detecting

```
if data5 == 5:
    print("data5 = 5")
```

impossible, it never triggers! Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just `.strip` the extra whitespace from `data5`?

Comment: i tried that but it kept causing errors i know it should work too but just haven't gotent it to work any time maby i'm just being dum dum :P

Comment: Then **tell us what the errors are**. Learn [ask], this isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: oh ye sorry it it removed the problem in cosole that there were no spaces between of numbers (like in 2nd code example) but still detecting didn't work ps: i dont have the code what i tested it at so... i can try to make it agein just takes little time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because data5 is Type string, not an Type int.

Try to cast it to an int using the following:

```
if int(data5) == 5:
```

Comment: Anytime! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

`data5 = f.readline()` brings back `5\n` and not `5`

If you do `data5 = f.readline().replace('\n','')` your code will work (well, you do need to check for a string `'5'`)

Alternatively change the if statement to: `if data5.replace('\n','') == '5':`

There are various other methods you can use to strip the `\n`

Comment: so if i understanded right if i do `5\n` does it come back as 5 and then empty space?